# flask Template Inheritance tutorial

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am running through the flask tutorial and I can not seem to get the Template Inheritance to work. below are the examples of my code

My base.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% block head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Webpage</title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
    <div id="footer">
        {% block footer %}
        &copy; Copyright 2008 by <a href="http://domain.invalid/">you</a>.
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my child Temp is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
    <style type="text/css">
        .important { color: #336699; }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <p class="important">
      Welcome to my awesome homepage.
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

my flask script is:

```
from flask import Flask,  render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("base.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Is there something specifically I should be doing regarding how I am incorporating the child template?  Or should I be rendering the base template differently?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jinja `extends` works (superficially) like Python subclassing.  You don't get an instance of a subclass when you instantiate a parent class, and you don't get the result of a child template when rendering the base template.  Render the child template instead.

```
return render_template('child.html')
```